# Code Seg Faults after atleast 375 Successful Entries

Tags: c

In a hash dictionary I'm working on, according to GDB the array has resized once from 500 to 1000. The array index it crashes trying to add is 799, so it's not out of bounds... I'm not sure why it's seg faulting, especially on such a seemingly harmless line. Here's the relevant code.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE *src = fopen(argv[1], "r");
int algnum = 1;
char input[40];
struct HT *table = create();


if (argc == 3)
{
    if (strcmp(argv[2], "0") == 0)
    {
        algnum = 0; 
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[2], "1") == 0)
    {
        algnum = 1;
    }
}

while(fgets(input, 40, src) != 0)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(input[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    struct word *wrd = malloc(sizeof(struct word));
    wrd->letters = input;
    wrd->length = i;
    if (algnum = 0)
    {
        add(table, wrd, &alg0);
    }
    else if (algnum = 1)
    {
        add(table, wrd, &alg1);
    }
}
}
```

Then in the include file...

```
struct HT* create() 
{
struct HT* table = malloc(sizeof(struct HT));
table->entries = 0;
table->num_buckets = 500;
table->largest_bucket = 0;
table->occupied_buckets = 0;
table->buckets = malloc(500 * sizeof(struct bucket*));
int i;  
for (i = 0; i<500; i++)
{
    table->buckets[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct bucket));
    table->buckets[i]->num_items = 0;
}
return table;   
}

struct HT* resize(struct HT* table, int(*alg)(struct word *wrd)) 
{
struct HT* table_new = malloc(sizeof(struct HT));
int new_size = 2*table->num_buckets;
table_new->buckets = malloc(new_size*sizeof(struct bucket*));
int i;  
for (i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
{
    table->buckets[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct bucket));
    table->buckets[i]->num_items = 0;
}
table_new->num_buckets = new_size;
table_new->occupied_buckets = 0;
table_new->entries = 0;
table_new->largest_bucket = 0;

struct word* wrd_temp = malloc(sizeof(struct word));
struct item* item_temp = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
for (i = 0; i<table->num_buckets; i++)
{
    item_temp = table->buckets[i]->head;
    while(item_temp != 0)
    {
        wrd_temp = item_temp->wrd;
        add(table_new, wrd_temp, alg);
        item_temp = item_temp->next;
    }
}
quit(table);
return table_new;
}

void add(struct HT* table, struct word *wrd, int(*alg)(struct word *wrd)) 
{
if ((double)table->entries / (double)table->num_buckets > .75)
{
    table = resize(table, alg);
}   
sort(wrd);
int code = alg(wrd);
code = code % table->num_buckets;
struct item* item_temp = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
struct item* item_add = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
item_add->wrd = wrd;
if (table->buckets[code]->head == 0)
{
    table->buckets[code]->head = item_add;
    table->occupied_buckets++;
}
else
{
    item_temp = table->buckets[code]->head;
    while (item_temp->next != 0) {
        item_temp = item_temp->next;
    }
    item_temp->next = item_add;
}
table->buckets[code]->num_items++;
table->entries++;
if (table->buckets[code]->num_items > table->largest_bucket)
{
    table->largest_bucket = table->buckets[code]->num_items;
}
}
```

EDIT: The line it's crashing on is:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400cbd in add (table=0x613cc0, wrd=0x613ca0, alg=0x400942 ) at ht.c:118
118     if (table->buckets[code]->head == 0)

REQUESTED INFO:

(gdb) print table->buckets[799]
$2 = (struct bucket *) 0x0

Comment: All entries `letters` members will be the same. You make them _all_ point to the same array which will be updated as you read the file.

Comment: what is the value of table->buckets[code] just before the segmentation?

Comment: As for the error, which line is line 118?

Comment: Also, when resizing the allocated memory, wouldn't it have been easier to use [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I suppose the hash code depends on the size of the table, so stuff needs to go into different buckets after a resize.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in `resize` you create a completely new `HT` structure. But in `add` you don't pass this back up the call-chain, so in `main` you still have your *old* `HT` structure.

And as an extra side-note, you never `free` anything so you have lots of memory leaks.

---

In `main` you create a new table. Lets call this table 1. Later when it's getting full you're creating a *new* table, lets call this 2. This new table is returned by `resize` and used in `add`. But when `add` returns the `main` function still has a pointer to table 1.

So when `add` is called next time, the `main` function passes table 1, which is too small so `resize` is called and creates yet *another* table, 3, that is used only locally in `add`. And so on and so on...

Comment: I don't think that's it. When I do print table->num_buckets at the time of the seg-fault I get 1000, meaning it HAS resized.

Comment: @SwiftCore It's because you have then called `resize` _again_. You will actually call `resize` _every_ time in `add` after the first time, without even adding the new data to the proper places.

Comment: But after I call it, it has a new num_buckets, so it should skip over the resize branch?

Comment: @SwiftCore You can actually debug this easily by temporarily set the size small, so it has to resize early. Then step though the code in the debugger, entering `add` and `resize`, while checking e.g. `table` in the different functions.

Comment: @SwiftCore No because then it's the _old_ structure pointer from `main` being used, the one not updated or resized. If you would have free'd the old structures after resizing, you would have gotten another segfault in `resize` instead because the pointers would already have been free'd.

Comment: I shortened it like you suggested. It seg faults immediately after returning from the resize, before returning to main and calling add again. Also, I do free them, the function quit() frees all the buckets and the table itself. Any thoughts?

Comment: @SwiftCore Please see my updated answer with a simple description of what happens.

Comment: I actually changed add() to return a table, and then update that table in main. But I don't think that is the problem, as it never actually gets back to main after resize().

Comment: Ah! It was that in resize, I was never actually allocating new buckets to the correct table. Thank you for your help.